# Flutter internet address.lookup always return connect true

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to check the internet connectivity but it always return connect true

```
 try {
  final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
  if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
    connect = 'true';
  }
} on SocketException catch (_) {
         connect = 'false';

}
print(connect);
return connect;
```

Comment: I believe this would only tell you if you have a connection up, not that if it's properly working, have you tried turning off wifi AND mobile data and then running it as that works for me personally. Another thing that comes to mind, are you using an emulator?

Comment: no am using a real device for running my app , as when I turn wifi on without any access of internet it return true  , this only check you are connecting or not with both wifi and mobile data  without checking the access of the internet connection

Comment: that's correct, that's what I was telling you, it won't check if your internet works but rather if you're connected or not. And I could be 100% wrong but I remember looking into this and it's more of an android issue from what I remember.

Comment: correct , but the aim here to check the google connection (access of network)  I think so , whether it connect to mobile data or wifi

Comment: I believe you need to find a different way to do that, this piece of code won't do it

Comment: Okay , thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0):

i know this question is about 2 years ago
but i had this problem today and i found how to solve it
maybe it can help to somebody else...

instead of connectivity_plus you should be used internet_connection_checker package which available in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker#license)

after add this package in your pubspec.yaml file you can add a listener in initState method

```
  var listener = InternetConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen((event) {
  // Your Code here
});
```

this listener provided a InternetConnectionStatus as event
also you can use this package in combination with connectivity

```
var isDeviceConnected = false;

var subscription = 
Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) async {
   if(result != ConnectivityResult.none) {
       isDeviceConnected = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
   }
});
```